# Package (rworldmap) can not be loaded in R software

Tags: r, package, rworldmap

When I load the `rworldmap` package, it can not be loaded in R software (version: 3.0.3).

```
The rworldmap package has been installed.
Code: library(rworldmap)

Wrong information appeared on the window as follows:

" Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘fields’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rworldmap’ "
```

How to tackle it?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Try to install.packages("fields") and then try again.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it seems to be insufficient. My soultion is: install three packages (fields, maptools, rgeos), and then reload the rworldmap package, and it works well.                                            Best

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Install package map 
library("ggmap")
library(maptools)
library(maps)
map("world", fill=TRUE, col="white", bg="lightblue", ylim=c(-60, 90), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in **R studio**
where Dependent packages are automatically get installed .

In base R you Want this packages 
package ‘spam’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fields’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rworldmap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked