# rworldmap error in R on install.packages()

Tags: r, install.packages, rworldmap

I'm having issues on loading the **rworldmap** with an error of fields. I found a post with the same error, however, the resolution did not work. In addition, my R version is **R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)**

[Package (rworldmap) can not be loaded in R software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817002/package-rworldmap-can-not-be-loaded-in-r-software)

```
  > install.packages("rworldmap", dependencies = TRUE )
   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/johnw/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
  (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
   also installing the dependencies ‘e1071’, ‘fields’, ‘rgdal’, 
  ‘rworldxtra’, ‘classInt’


    There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
   binary source needs_compilation
   fields    9.0    9.6              TRUE

    Binaries will be installed
   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/e1071_1.6-
   8.zip'
   Content type 'application/zip' length 894561 bytes (873 KB)
  downloaded 873 KB

  trying URL 
  'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/fields_9.0.zip'
  Warning in install.packages :
 cannot open URL 
 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/fields_9.0.zip': HTTP 
  status was '404 Not Found'
  Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 
  'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/fields_9.0.zip'
  Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘fields’ failed
 trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rgdal_1.2-
 16.zip'
 Content type 'application/zip' length 30479400 bytes (29.1 MB)
 downloaded 29.1 MB

 trying URL 
'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rworldxtra_1.01.zip'
 Content type 'application/zip' length 5273807 bytes (5.0 MB)
 downloaded 5.0 MB

  trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/classInt_0.1-
  24.zip'
  Content type 'application/zip' length 60087 bytes (58 KB)
  downloaded 58 KB

  trying URL 
 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rworldmap_1.3-6.zip'
 Content type 'application/zip' length 2872574 bytes (2.7 MB)
 downloaded 2.7 MB

package ‘e1071’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rworldxtra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘classInt’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rworldmap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

Even when trying to directly load the field package, I receive the below error:

```
   > install.packages("fields")
    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/johnw/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
   binary source needs_compilation
 fields    9.0    9.6              TRUE

 Binaries will be installed
 trying URL 
'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/fields_9.0.zip'
 Warning in install.packages :
 cannot open URL 
'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/fields_9.0.zip': HTTP 
 status was '404 Not Found'
 Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
 cannot open URL 
'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/fields_9.0.zip'
 Warning in install.packages :
 download of package ‘fields’ failed
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try by downloading from github: `devtools::install_github('AndySouth/rworldmap', build_vignettes=TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you. However it returned the same error upon installing from github. Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL -l "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIVoxZE\Rinst33b42175297" --no-multiarch "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpIVoxZE/Rbuild33b494b7438/rworldmap"' had status 1
      -----------------------------------
ERROR: dependency 'fields' is not available for package 'rworldmap'
* removing 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpIVoxZE/Rinst33b42175297/rworldmap'
In R CMD INSTALL

Comment: This is a silly question, but do you have internet connection?

Comment: Yes, I have a connection. I ran the below in sequences: install.packages('devtools')
library('devtools')
devtools::install_github('AndySouth/rworldmap', build_vignettes=TRUE)